# Given $\epsilon$, find $\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Given $\epsilon=0.01$ and $a=2$. Find a value $\delta$ corresponding to the given value of $\epsilon$ so that the definition of continuity is satisfied.

I supposed, that since $f(x)=f(a)+\epsilon$, we could solve the equation $$f(x)-f(a)=\epsilon$$$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}=0.01/-0.01$$

for $x$, choose the smallest $x$, then find the $\delta$ that is sufficiently small, so the change in the value of the function remains within $0.01$. Why doesn't this method work? The correct answer is $2\epsilon$.

Comment: "Given =0.01, find a value  such that $f()=\sqrt x$ is continuous at =2." This question has no sense !

Comment: @Surb: obviously, but you can fix as "give a $\delta$ that matches $\epsilon=0.01$ in the condition for continuity.

Comment: More precisely "Find a value $\delta$ corresponding to the given value of $\epsilon$ so that the definition of continuity is satisfied"

Comment: @juhani: no, this is wrong. Continuity requires that the condition holds for *all* $\epsilon$. To be even more specific I should have said "inequality".

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it in a different way and still a dead end. Here is my work.

$$\vert \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2} \vert<0.01$$$$-0.01<\vert \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}<0.01$$

$$-0.01+\sqrt{2} < \sqrt{x} < 0.01+\sqrt{x}$$

$$(-0.01+\sqrt{2})^2 < x < (0.01+\sqrt{x})^2$$

$$-0.028184 < x - 2 < 0.028384$$

The correct answer should be $\delta = 0.028184$, but the given answer is $\delta = 0.02$. Is this because any *smaller* $\delta$ is also a valid answer? Seems a bit arbitrary to me. This is all from the book *A first course in real analysis - Protter, Morrey*.

Comment: "Is this because any smaller δ is also a valid answer?" - yes. Think of continuity as playing a game against a mean adversary. He picks some distance $\epsilon$ and challenges you to find a number $\delta$ so that whenever the function is no more than $\delta$ away from some $x$, the output will be no more than $\epsilon$ away from $f(x)$. Once you've found one particular $\delta$, then any smaller value will also work. If it's possible for you to do this no matter what $\epsilon$ the adversary picks, then the function is continuous at $x$.

Comment: The problem statement is asking *a* value. $0.02$ is indeed *a* correct answer, but not *the* correct answer. Nor is $2-(\sqrt2-0.01)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\sqrt x$ is monotonic, so that in an interval it achieves the minimum and maximum value at the endpoints.

We try $\delta=10^{-10}$:

$$\left|\sqrt{2\pm10^{-10}}-\sqrt2\right|=\frac{10^{-10}}{\sqrt{2\pm10^{-10}}+\sqrt2}<10^{-10}<0.01$$ is true and we are done.